# Syncfusion Dashboard Platform: how to make dashboards fast?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, syncfusion, bigdata

I've setted up **Syncfusion Dashboard Platform** to work with some imported test data (**Syncfusion Big Data**).

I have used Integration platform for import in Hadoop (files are stored in **Avro** format).

Then I put Avro data from Hadoop to Hive tables via Spark SQL (convert Avro to table), in total I have 400 rows.

Then I used this **Hive2** as Datasource in Dashboard platform.

Then I tried to fetch the data and it works very slowly.

Can somebody point me how to figure it out? Settings in Syncfusion are by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended Solution:**

As Hive Server2(Map Reduce) is well suited for batch processing with large data set, I recommend you to use **Spark SQL** data source for near real time analytics such as dashboard visualization. Because Spark SQL process data in-memory to avoid multiple disk I/O operations.

•   Tables created under the Hive can also be accessed from “**Spark SQL**” in Syncfusion distribution as both uses same meta store database.
So you can use the “**Spark SQL**” connection type in Syncfusion Dashboard platform instead of “**Hive**”.